# How to speed up this for loop by replace the append function

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, append

I have an append function at the end of a for loop that's causing my code to take 5 minutes to run. I am wondering if there is a better way to write the code, so it will run faster. Thank you.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range(len(ABC['abc'])):
    x = ABC['start_time'][i]
    y = ABC['end_time'][i]

    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(x,y , freq='1min')).rename(columns={0: 'END_TIME'})
    df['start_time'] = x
    df['WEIGHT'] =  range(1, len(df) + 1)
    dff = df.merge(ABC, on = 'start_time', how='left')      
    df2= df2.append(dff, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: The most straight-forward way is to append to a list, then `pd.concatenate(list_of_dfs)` at the end. There may be a better approach alltogether, but that would be the most direct solution.

Comment: Thank @juanpa.arrivillaga. I tried concat but it didn't help much. I ended up moving the merge and drop_duplicate out of the loop and that ended up speeding up the code by 7X.